# Android: how to find out, if activity was started or resumed (comes to foreground) from outside of application

Tags: android

Consider following situation:

I have an application, which contains some critical information (e.g. banking app). The application itself has multiple screens.

I would like to have the following behavior: Every time after application becomes inactive for any reason (e.g.: user pressed "home" button, user switched to other app using list of recent tasks, user shut down display with power button, input call happened etc...)... so every time after that I want, that when user comes back to the app, the password is requested.

The first solution, which comes to mind is to request password every time in `onResume()`. But this of course does not work, because this method is also called, when internal transition from one activity to another within the application happens (and of course, at this point the password should not be requested).

So to solve this I would need to know, if `onResume()` was triggered from "internal transition" or from outside the application.

I would be very grateful, if someone could suggest, how to do it.

If there is another solution to the problem, I would also be happy to know it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `ProcessLifecycleOwner`

ProcessLifecycleOwner is a special kind of LifecycleOwner that is a composite of all of your Activities. It provides lifecycle for the whole application process

```
   implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0"
   implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"
   annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0"
```

Create an `Application` class and set custom app lifecycle observer

```
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(appLifecycleObserver)
    }
}
```

Custom `LifecycleObserver` class

```
class AppLifecycleObserver : LifecycleObserver {

    /**
     * When application come to Foreground
     */
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onEnterForeground() {
        // do something
    }

    /**
     * When application goes to Background
     */
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onEnterBackground() {
        // do something
    }

}
```

You check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner) for detail explanation and [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/react-to-app-foreground-and-background-events-with-processlifecycleowner-96278e5816fa).

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for. Two small additions: I used more recent version of dependencies: `lifecycle-common-java8` and `lifecycle-process` (with version 2.2.0) instead of `lifecycle-extensions` and `lifecycle-compiler`. And second (probably obvious, but was not for me): To start new activity one does not need to know currently active activity to use as a context, - instead one can use `Application` as a context.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to do actually. You didn't specify any programming language. So, I am working with `Java`. There's something called `sharedPreferences` where you can store data. You have initialize it.

```
//Declare shared Preference
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

Then, file location

```
//declare shared prefernce file name
public final String PREFS_GAME="com.istiak.sharedpreference.Game";
```

Then, mode

```
//Creating SharedPreferences name game and mode is private
pref=getSharedPreferences(PREFS_GAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
editor=pref.edit();
```

To save data

```
editor.putInt("highScore",score);
                editor.apply();
```

To get data

```
int getSaveScore=pref.getInt("highScore",0);
```

Here is my [git repo](https://github.com/Istiakshovon/SharedPreference/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/istiak/sharedpreference/MainActivity.java)
You can save user password on sharePreferences. So, when you is reopening the activity than check `getSaveScore` `getPassword`(for you) empty or not

Comment: Sorry, but I believe you were answering not the question, which I was asking. My question was not how to persist password data, while the app goes to background (by the way, I believe that `SharedPreferences` is not the most secure storage for the password), but rather how to find out, when application comes from background to foreground (becomes active), so that I can ask user for the password again).