Android : Stop music in background and play again in foreground
Using the service, I made it so that Android does not stop playing music
class Sound(): Service() {
    private var mainSoundPlayer = MediaPlayer()
    override fun onBind(arg0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        mainSoundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mainsound)
        mainSoundPlayer.isLooping = true
        mainSoundPlayer.start()
    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}

But the problem is that when I use the recent key and back key, the music does not stop, and I want the music to stop and when the program is opened from the recent app, the music will be played again.

you can pause the music using onEnterForeground from LifecycleObserver when app comes to foreground when music is playing. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/65835178/3189909

The reason it is happening is because services continue running even if user press back, home or recent. service onDestroy() will be called when service
is stopped by code internally by calling stopSelf() or stopService().
so, you can override lifeCycle onPause()/onStop()/onResume() methods for your activity where you start your service to call stopSelf()/stopServcie().
